# Efficiently join two large point layers by location

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, spatial-join

I need to join two point layers containing several million points each. One has an ID and population density, the other has an ID and a settlement model (SMOD) categorization. The attributes of those features that share (roughly) the same coordinates should be joined. By that I  mean that if any of the two layers has a feature at a certain location in the output layer there should be a feature containing the attributes of at least one input layer and maybe a second layer. So I used the algorithm "join attributes by location".

In a small example in the area of Melilla I use a layer with Population density (1.624 point features) and a layer with a settlement model (6.381 point features):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10hwwLrNNfq_KrHlTINsUd2qr-sgJCjh_/view?usp=sharing

Unfortunately QGIS 3.20.1 required more than 1 hour to calculate this although it was just a tiny part compared to the data I need to apply the "join by location" algorithm to.
Why is it so slow? Is the algorithm comparing each point of one layer to each point of the other layer? Are there no spatial indexes used? Or is it so slow even though a spatial index is used and if so why?

If the latter is the case does anybody know smarter alternatives (other algorithms/methods) to achieve the same results?

Comment: Please extend your tags with software tools you would like to use

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the format of the data tables and what effort you have made toward indexing them.

Comment: @Bera when I open the files in QGIS, they are recognized as `ESRI:54009 - World_Mollweide` and are correctly projected to Melilla and surroundings (northern Marocco).

Answer (score 2):

For me, it works in less then a second (without spatial index: less than 3 secs.), using the data you provided. Create a spatial index: Right click layer / Properties / Source tab / Create spatial index. Then run `Join by location`. Be sure to select `Take attributes of the first matching feature only (one-to-one)`:

[image]

See the result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This absolutely worked. I had followed the same steps but as a selection on the original data which was why it took more than one hour. I susprect a bug in QGIS.

Comment: What about the non-matching features (nicht verknüpfbare Objekte aus dem ersten Layer [Optional]? I get exactly 4 points and I have no idea why.. Should I put this into a separate question?

Comment: Well - basically it would help if you stated a bit more in detail what exactly you want to do. You speak about "features that share (roughly) the same coordinates should be joined". When speaking about points (as in your case) they either have **exactly** the same coordinates or they do not overlap at all. What about duplicate points? Do you have several points in the same location? I also guess your dataset is heavily overloaded and I'm not sure if you really need to work with a global dataset? Can't you first prepare your data, reducing file size?

Answer (score 0):

After rerunning the algorithm I need to respond to my own core question which was why the algorithm took so long. As I originally run the algorithm on the given data as a selection of a larger data set I suspected I was doing something wrong. I then exported the selected features (my small example in the area of Melilla) and published it here.

Yet the root cause seems to be a different handling in QGIS between the processing of selected data (which took 1 hour) and the processing of layers (which took 3 s). I filed a report as I am suspecting an inappropriate behaviour in QGIS:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44890

Comment: Please report back here any bug fixes , further clarifications etc

Comment: By the way: when testing with a selection: did you run it with a spatial index? can you somehow share the whole file?

Comment: Both original files possess spatial indexes. The original files can be referred to at the issue on github. I can report back once there is a solution. Until then it makes more sense to discuss the topic there rather than having a duplicate discussion about the root cause here.

Comment: Your datasets contain 26 millions respectively over 145 millions points! No wonder it takes a long time to proceed: simply loading the data takes a lot of time. Do you really need the whole dataset? It seems way too much. Do you really need to process data on a worldwide? Or do you have a focused region of interest? I would start by reducing the filesize and get rid of unnecessary features

Comment: Your data seems to be converted from a raster, right? Do you have access to this raster? I guess it would be easier to work with that. If you really need dozens of millions of points, consider using a PostGIS database. I try to load your Geopackage, it's running for almost half an hour now (without any geoprossessing, simply loading)... So maybe the performance of your machine, throughput etc. plays a more important role here than any QGIS-specific problem.

Comment: I agree it is best to reduce the data only to the size that is required. Unfortunately I really need that much data for a worldwide evaluation in the end and I'll most probably need it in point data for later processing steps. I can post the greater topic of my task in 2 weeks as a new topic. It might be interesting to everyone. I am on the edge of my vacation and about to leave.
Returning to the original question: As the datasets are indexed processing that little data shouldn't take that long which is why I reported it to QGIS development. The QGIS project is always grateful for reports.

Comment: Still maybe worth thinking if you can proceed with raster data as long as possible and only later convert to points. Have a nice holiday.